# Setting header text of a DisclosurePanel dynamically while preserving the arrow icon?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I'd like to set the text in DisclosurePanel's header without having to re-construct the image/icon used by the default header.

Using customHeader means the arrow-icon is lost, in other words that seems like unreasonable amount of extra work.

EDIT: There's actually method for that, getHeaderTextAccessor(String)

Comment: Not an awnser, but for future projects: Check out Vaadin (http://vaadin.com/), our Java programmers like it better then GWT or Smart-GWT. It also uses GWT under the hood but appearantly has a nicer API.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not interested in another framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[getHeaderTextAccessor(String)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DisclosurePanel.html#getHeaderTextAccessor())

Comment: Wow, this API was really well-hidden. I was looking for setHeaderText(). Thanks!